# Get value of field by string

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to get the value of a field of an object by using a string as variable name.
I tried to do this with reflection:

```
myobject.GetType().GetProperty("Propertyname").GetValue(myobject, null);
```

This works perfectly but now I want to get the value of "sub-properties":

```
public class TestClass1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TestClass2 SubProperty = new TestClass2();
}

public class TestClass2
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Here I want to get the value `Address` from a object of `TestClass1`.

Comment: `Field` is not a `Property`, what you are referring here is a `property`

Answer (score 24):

You already did everything you need to do, you just have to do it twice:

```
TestClass1 myobject = ...;
// get SubProperty from TestClass1
TestClass2 subproperty = (TestClass2) myobject.GetType()
    .GetProperty("SubProperty")
    .GetValue(myobject, null);
// get Address from TestClass2
string address = (string) subproperty.GetType()
    .GetProperty("Address")
    .GetValue(subproperty, null);
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `SubProperty` member is actually a `Field` and not a `Property`, that is why you can not access it by using the `GetProperty(string)` method. In your current scenario, you should use the following class to first get the `SubProperty` field, and then the `Address` property.

This class will allow you to specify the return type of your property by closing the type `T` with the appropriate type. Then you will simply need to add to the first parameter the *object* whose members you are extracting. The second parameter is the name of the field you are extracting while the third parameter is the name of the property whose value you are trying to get.

```
class SubMember<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public SubMember(object source, string field, string property)
    {
        var fieldValue = source.GetType()
                               .GetField(field)
                               .GetValue(source);

        Value = (T)fieldValue.GetType()
                             .GetProperty(property)
                             .GetValue(fieldValue, null);
    }
}
```

In order to get the desired value in your context, simply execute the following lines of code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var t1 = new TestClass1();

        Console.WriteLine(new SubMember<string>(t1, "SubProperty", "Address").Value);            
    }
}
```

This will give you the value contained in the `Address` property. Just make sure you first add a value to the said property.

But should you actually want to change the field of your class into a property, then you should make the following change to the original `SubMember` class.

```
class SubMemberModified<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public SubMemberModified(object source, string property1, string property2)
    {
        var propertyValue = source.GetType()
                                  .GetProperty(property1)
                                  .GetValue(source, null);

        Value = (T)propertyValue.GetType()
                                .GetProperty(property2)
                                .GetValue(propertyValue, null);
    }
}
```

This class will now allow you to extract the property from your initial class, and get the value from the second property, which is extracted from the first property.

Answer (score 5):

try

```
 myobject.GetType().GetProperty("SubProperty").GetValue(myobject, null)
 .GetType().GetProperty("Address")
 .GetValue(myobject.GetType().GetProperty("SubProperty").GetValue(myobject, null), null);
```